# Importance of laser numerical aperture in selecting photo diode

Tags: photodiode, laser, laser-diode, transimpedance, photonics

I want to design a  circuit in which the laser light will be detected by a photodiode. I just wanted to know how the laser numerical aperture will affect the photodiode selection.

Am I have to concern about the Numerical aperture and other things like acceptance angle, the divergence angle of the laser, for selecting the photodiode. Please share your experience it will be a great help. (Sorry for my bad English :( )
Thank you.

Comment: Is this for free-space communications or will you be routing the signal through fiber?  Or is it just for an opto-interruptor type application?

Comment: Add some links or part numbers for your laser/led.

Comment: @ThePhoton I am using a fiber.

Comment: If you're using a fiber then you need to use some kind of optics to couple the laser light into the fiber. The design of those optics depends on the NA of the laser and of the fiber. If you bought a laser module of some kind, the optics may be included in the module.

Comment: Then you need to use optics to couple the fiber output to the detector. Again the design depends on the fiber NA. Again the optics may already be included if you bought a detector module rather than just a bare photodiode. The laser NA will not affect your photodiode selection at all.

Comment: Also, for the last 40 years or more, in English the word *laser* is treated as an ordinary word and not an acronym or initialism. There's no need to capitalize it, and it looks funny if you do.

Comment: I am using a bare photodiode with trans amplifier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ThePhoton  It concludes that I don't want to bother about the N.A. of the laser. One more thing I want to ask is regarding the active area of the photodiode. Is less active area photodiode is less sensitive? Or it totally depends on the laser spot- if the active area is sufficient enough to capture the spot of the laser, then active area greater than this won't affects or increase the sensitivity of the photodiode.

Comment: If you have more questions, you can post them as new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a laser is one thing, and an LED is something else. If you bought something marketed as a "LASER LED" that's just a marketing or trade name and it has no technical meaning.

Numerical aperture is the sine of the half-angle of divergence of a beam. An N.A. of 0 would indicate a perfectly collimated beam (a physical impossibility) while an N.A. of 1 would indicate the beam spreads over a full \$2\pi\$ steradians, i.e. it emits into the entire half sphere in front of the emitter.

If you're talking about simply directing the beam from an emitter toward a detector, a lower NA would mean you can get a larger fraction of the total light onto any given emitter at some distance away. A larger NA would mean you don't need to be so accurate in pointing your emitter in exactly the right direction.

More likely if you're trying to cover more than a few centimeters of distance, you'll need to use some kind of optics. Since this would be designed to take light from a point source and project it in a collimated beam, optics engineers call it a *telescope*. The NA of the emitter gives a requirement on the design of the telescope if you want to capture most of the light from the emitter.

The N.A. of the emitter has very little impact on the choice of detector unless the distance between them is very short (a few mm at most) and you want to choose a detector diameter to capture the whole emitter output.

Comment: More Info: The LASER is not directly pointing the photodiode, the LASER and photodiode are on the same plane.  
Yes, I want to capture the whole emitter output. So I have to concern on which parameter of the photodiode.